# Golang to Json, creating Google Charts

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm using Polymer Google Charts. I want to create JSON for a single Controller.ServeJSON call, but two if it's better design.

Here is an example of what the JSON would include if it was two call.

cols='[{"label":"Mth", "type":"string"}, {"label":"Days", "type":"number"}]'
rows='[["Jan", 31],["Feb", 28],["Mar", 31]]'

And if it was one

data='[["Month", "Days"], ["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31]]'

This can be found at https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-chart

I used https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to convert the JSON into a struct.

Assuming Two Calls, Got this..

```
    type Chart struct {
        Cols []struct {
            Label string `json:"label"`
            Type  string `json:"type"`
        } `json:"cols"`
        Rows []struct {
            Num0 string `json:"0"`
            Num1 int    `json:"1"`
```

All help and advice would be most appreciated.

Cheers.

EDIT..

```
    func (c *ChillController) Get() {

jsonString := "[[\"Month\", \"Days\"], [\"Jan\", 31], [\"Feb\", 28], [\"Mar\", 31]]"
d := [][]Chart{}

json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &d)

fmt.Printf("%v", &d)

c.Data["json"] = &d
c.ServeJSON()
```

}

And it returned..

[
  [
    null,
    null
  ],
  [
    null,
    null
  ]
]

What have I missed.

Answer (score 1):

I always use json-to-go is one of my favorites tool, but I found a bug https://github.com/mholt/json-to-go/issues/18

Your struct should looks like: `type Chart [][]interface{}` in other words a slice of slices. See this question too [Unmarshall nested JSON Arrays in Go / Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902502/unmarshall-nested-json-arrays-in-go-golang)

**Edit:**

More specific your **rows** is a slice of slices of strings and numbers, so sadly we have to use something similar what I wrote you: `[][]interface{}` because a slice has to have the same type and in this case we have strings and numbers so the solution is empty interface{}. Also always try to use ticks `` to represent raw Json in Go it looks better and you don't have to escape quotes.

```
jsonString := `[
    ["Month", "Days"], ["Jan", 31], ["Feb", 28], ["Mar", 31]
]`

var rows [][]interface{}

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &rows)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
    return
}

fmt.Printf("%+v \n\n", rows)

for _, row := range rows { // each row in this example is just one

    if len(row) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("unexpected row len")
        continue // or return error
    }

    // we can access to [0] or [1]

    month := row[0].(string) // column 1
    day := row[1]            // column 2

    if dayNumber, isNumber := day.(float64); isNumber { // by default use the biggest type for numbers float64
        fmt.Println("Month:", month, "Day number:", dayNumber)
        continue
    }

    if dayStr, isString := day.(string); isString {
        fmt.Println("Month:", month, "Day string:", dayStr)
        continue
    }
}
```

Full example: https://play.golang.org/p/ZGtBRqP3Uj

Comment: Thanks. I don't full grasp the concept it seems. I tried to implement that change. See the edit above. What am I missing.

Comment: You're trying to Unmarshal a slice into a Chart struct, a little trick: if you see '{ }' in the json use structs of maps, and '[ ]' for slices. I edited my answer too :)